# How to pull guids from a webpage using html, javascript, jquery, and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm writing a program that allows the user to select a bunch of products and the page displays them by relation.  At the bottom of the page I'd like a submit to cart button that searches the whole page and pulls out the product guids (that I've assigned as ids as they are appended) and builds a cartArray of these guids.  Then I'll just loop through the array and post those guids to our cart api.

All elements are stored in the #product-container as their root element, so I clicked through and cut the element for a better example, though I'm expecting even larger product-containers:

```
<div id="product-container">
        <!--Outdoor Unit Selection Toggle-->
        <div id="outdoor-selection-toggle" class="unselected hidden">
            <div class="sub-header">Choose an Outdoor Model to Begin</div>
        </div>
        <!--Selected Outdoor Unit container-->
        <div id="selected-outdoor-unit">
        <div id="601eb6c8-125f-4b67-b1fc-a905013f12a6" class="outdoor-unit-option modal-option selected">
                    <div class="unit-header">
                        <div class="outdoor-product-description sub-header2">CONDENSER HEAT PUMP 12 mbh 208/230/1 15 SEER MIDEA<a class="close-button" href="javascript:location.reload();">×</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit-body">
                        <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/38MHR_3_highest-res_Large.jpg">
                        <div class="product-information-container">
                            <div class="product-information model-number">Model Number: 38MHRBQ12AA3</div>
                            <div class="product-information qtyOnHand">9 Available</div>
                            <div class="product-information indoor-min">Min Indoor Units Required: 2</div> 
                            <div class="product-information indoor-max">Max Indoor Units Required: 5</div>
                            <a class="product-information more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/38mhrbq12aa3" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div>

        <!--Selected Indoor Unit Containers-->
        <div id="indoor1" class="indoor-selection-toggle-container">
            <!--Branch Box-->
            <div class="main-branch-box">
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="top-branch selected-branch selected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="bottom-branch selected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--selection box-->
            <div id="indoor-selection1" class="indoor-selection indoor-selection-toggle selected"><div id="2d8fae09-90f2-4fd6-92a3-a82e012742aa" class="selected-indoor-unit">
                    <div class="unit-header">
                        <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2">HEAT PUMP WALL UNIT 12 mbh 208/230/1 15 SEER MIDEA</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit-body">
                        <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/40MHH_1_highest-res_Large.jpg">
                        <div class="product-information-container">
                            <div class="product-information model-number">Model Number: 40MHHQ12---3</div>
                            <div class="product-information qtyOnHand">2 Available</div>
                            <div class="product-information indoor-min">Min Indoor Units Required: 2</div>
                            <div class="product-information indoor-max">Max Indoor Units Required: 5</div>
                            <a class="product-information more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/40mhhq12-3" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a id="remove-indoor-unit1" class="remove-indoor-unit close-button">×</a>
                <!--accessory box-->
                <div id="indoor-accessory1" class="indoor-accessory-togglebox">
                    <div class="indoor-accessory-selection-toggle unselected">Add Accessories</div>
                <div id="67aa9644-0704-4f97-9492-a82e012723a4" class="indoor-accessory-selected">
                            <div class="unit-header">
                                <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2">WIRE STRANDED THHN 14/4 50' ROLL MINI SPLIT MARS</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="unit-body">
                                <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/m84479_Large_Large.jpg">
                                <div class="product-information-container">
                                    <div class="model-number">Model Number: M84479</div>
                                    <a class="more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/m84479" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="accessory-close-button close-button">×</a>
                        </div><div id="af88215d-5513-419a-963e-a82e012712ea" class="indoor-accessory-selected">
                            <div class="unit-header">
                                <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2">CONDENSATE SWITCH FOR MINI PAN SPLITS 0 - 250v RECTORSEAL</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="unit-body">
                                <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/97622_Large_Large.jpg">
                                <div class="product-information-container">
                                    <div class="model-number">Model Number: SS610E</div>
                                    <a class="more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/ss610e" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="accessory-close-button close-button">×</a>
                        </div></div>
                <!--selection toggle-->
                <div class="sub-header2 hidden">Select an indoor model</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="indoor2" class="indoor-selection-toggle-container">
            <!--Branch Box-->
            <div class="main-branch-box">
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="top-branch selected-branch selected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="bottom-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--selection box-->
            <div id="indoor-selection2" class="indoor-selection indoor-selection-toggle selected"><div id="2d8fae09-90f2-4fd6-92a3-a82e012742aa" class="selected-indoor-unit">
                    <div class="unit-header">
                        <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2">HEAT PUMP WALL UNIT 12 mbh 208/230/1 15 SEER MIDEA</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unit-body">
                        <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/40MHH_1_highest-res_Large.jpg">
                        <div class="product-information-container">
                            <div class="product-information model-number">Model Number: 40MHHQ12---3</div>
                            <div class="product-information qtyOnHand">2 Available</div>
                            <div class="product-information indoor-min">Min Indoor Units Required: 2</div>
                            <div class="product-information indoor-max">Max Indoor Units Required: 5</div>
                            <a class="product-information more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/40mhhq12-3" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a id="remove-indoor-unit2" class="remove-indoor-unit close-button">×</a>
                <!--accessory box-->
                <div id="indoor-accessory2" class="indoor-accessory-togglebox">
                    <div class="indoor-accessory-selection-toggle unselected">Add Accessories</div>
                <div id="67aa9644-0704-4f97-9492-a82e012723a4" class="indoor-accessory-selected">
                            <div class="unit-header">
                                <div class="indoor-product-description sub-header2">WIRE STRANDED THHN 14/4 50' ROLL MINI SPLIT MARS</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="unit-body">
                                <img class="product-image" src="http://www.behler-young.com/UserFiles/Product/m84479_Large_Large.jpg">
                                <div class="product-information-container">
                                    <div class="model-number">Model Number: M84479</div>
                                    <a class="more-info" href="https://www.behler-young.com/Product/m84479" target="_blank">More Information</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="accessory-close-button close-button">×</a>
                        </div></div>
                <!--selection toggle-->
                <div class="sub-header2 hidden">Select an indoor model</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="indoor3" class="indoor-selection-toggle-container">
            <!--Branch Box-->
            <div class="main-branch-box">
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="top-branch unselected-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="bottom-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--selection box-->
            <div id="indoor-selection3" class="indoor-selection unselected indoor-selection-toggle">
                <a id="remove-indoor-unit3" class="remove-indoor-unit close-button hidden">×</a>
                <!--accessory box-->
                <div id="indoor-accessory3" class="indoor-accessory-togglebox hidden">
                    <div class="indoor-accessory-selection-toggle unselected">Add Accessories</div>
                </div>
                <!--selection toggle-->
                <div class="sub-header2">Select an indoor model</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="indoor4" class="indoor-selection-toggle-container">
            <!--Branch Box-->
            <div class="main-branch-box">
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="top-branch unselected-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="bottom-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--selection box-->
            <div id="indoor-selection4" class="indoor-selection unselected indoor-selection-toggle">
                <a id="remove-indoor-unit4" class="remove-indoor-unit close-button hidden">×</a>
                <!--accessory box-->
                <div id="indoor-accessory4" class="indoor-accessory-togglebox hidden">
                    <div class="indoor-accessory-selection-toggle unselected">Add Accessories</div>
                </div>
                <!--selection toggle-->
                <div class="sub-header2">Select an indoor model</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="indoor5" class="indoor-selection-toggle-container">
            <!--Branch Box-->
            <div class="main-branch-box">
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="top-branch unselected-branch unselected-line">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-branch-box">
                    <div class="branch-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="bottom-branch ">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--selection box-->
            <div id="indoor-selection5" class="indoor-selection unselected indoor-selection-toggle">
                <a id="remove-indoor-unit5" class="remove-indoor-unit close-button hidden">×</a>
                <!--accessory box-->
                <div id="indoor-accessory5" class="indoor-accessory-togglebox hidden">
                    <div class="indoor-accessory-selection-toggle unselected">Add Accessories</div>
                </div>
                <!--selection toggle-->
                <div class="sub-header2">Select an indoor model</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="add-to-cart-button">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
```

I know our guids follow this regex `([a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12})`, but I don't know how to search the page's elments ids for matches to that regex and build the array.  It seems pretty straightforward though, but I'm having a hard time finding an example.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How in the HTML are those guids stored? At least add some example code to your question.

Comment: If you know the element which contains the values you just need to use `map()`. We can't really help you effectively without seeing the HTML, though

Comment: Keep in mind that valid HTML ID attributes cannot begin with a numeric character.

Comment: @RedYetiCo in HTML5 they can.

Comment: ask and ye shall receive - I was just setting the product parent divs ids equal to the product specific guid.

Comment: @DerekDH thanks for editing, but could you also show us the common parent element to where all those `div` elements which have the GUID id are held?

Comment: alright, I gave a much larger example, essentially I want to search all the elements w/in #product-container, if they have an id matching the regex pattern, drop it in an array.

Comment: alright - my brain was just stalling, going to slap a product class on every element when I append it and use jquery selector for those specific elements, pull ids that way.  I know this regex pattern matching is possible, but a bit overcomplicated (and probably slow) for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to provide too much detail specific to your markup as I think it would be better to illustrate the approach rather than provide the exact solution (give someone a fish, feed them that day, teach them to fish, and feed them for life).

Here's how I would approach the problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="products">
  <div id="32dfe88d-38c2-4501-965f-4615dd9dc05f" class="product">
    <div class="name">My Product</div>
  </div>
  <div id="69e7fbcf-3303-4f13-bd14-a82c943a9f28" class="product">
    <div class="name">My Product</div>
  </div>
  <div id="4146ab7e-c2ec-4353-aafb-9209ebb9ba52" class="product">
    <div class="name">My Product</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cart">
  <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

If you have control over the HTML output, I would add some detail to make your life easier, in this case, classifying the elements as `.product` would make sense. You can also limit the scope of how much you have to parse by wrapping it with a specific class, in this case `.products`.

**JS:**

```
( function( $ ) {
  $( function() {

    // Toggle product selection...
    $( '.products .product' ).on( 'click', function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( 'select' );
    } );

    // Construct a list of found IDs...
    $( '.cart .submit' ).on( 'click', function() {
      var MyIDs = [];
      $( '.products .product.select' ).each( function( i ) {
        var ThisID = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
        // Validation rules go here...
        MyIDs.push( ThisID );
      } );
      // Submit the ids here...
      alert( MyIDs.join( "\n" ) );
    } );

  } );
} )( jQuery );
```

It shouldn't take much to gather these IDs (though I *highly* recommend using something like `data-product-guid="..."` instead of the ID attribute due to alleviating potential issues with other languages). Also, please keep in mind EVERYTHING submitted to your system should be treated as suspicious. Even though you can validate the IDs being collected with this approach, **you should always validate on the backend as well**.

What you'll see in this example are places where you can apply any sort of validation (in this case you would test the ID value against a regex pattern) and decide whether or not you want to add it to the list of valid IDs; additionally you'll see where you can initiate the submit process.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I'd upvote ya but I haven't the reputation (and this post won't help that).  In your example, wouldn't you want to use the child selector like this ```$('.products > .product')```, (https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), I think ```$('.products.product')``` would only hook things with both products and product classes, which in this case is nothing.

Comment: Good catch, will update these typos. I would advise not using the `>` direct descendant selector when possible since HTML can commonly change as a product matures, this just helps keep it flexible should you need to include a wrapper down the line.